# Вывод в консоль элементов через запятую C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть условие

```
if (i < 15)
```

Мне нужно все i записать в строку с разделителем запятая ( необходимо записать все числа в переменную с разделителем запятая)

Comment: А что это за `i` такое. У вас есть массив со всеми возможными вариантами `i`? Это натуральные числа ниже 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Уточнение

С вашего описания к вопросу предполагаю что у вас есть некий массив цифр...

```cs
var values = new int[] { 5, 18, 22, 3, 0, -8, 625 };
```

...и вы должны записать их всех в строку с разделителем те которые ниже 15.

#### Ответ

Кратко и правильно будет так:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values.Where(value => value < 15)));
```

Но раз обязательно нужен через `if` преобразуем вот так:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", values.Where((value) => {
    if (value < 15) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
})));
```

---

Выглядит по-идиотски. Передайте, пожалуйста это тому кто дал вас такое задание.

Comment: `.ToList()` - зачем?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу прощения.

Answer (score 1):

Порядок будет обратный (если надо прямой - инвертировать условие в for), решение основано на предположениях, что нужны неотрицательный числа, 0 не нужен

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 15; i > 0; i--)
{
   list.Add(i);
}

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", list));
```

Comment: А смысл в `.ToString()`?

Comment: Compilation error (line 11, col 4): The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments
Compilation error (line 11, col 13): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'
Если убрать

Comment: Так коллекцию сделайте `int`, а не `string`, зачем вы делаете конвертацию числа в строку лишнюю?

Comment: согласен, логично

Comment: нужно именно с if

Answer (score 0):

Тогда можно так:

```
var list = new List<int>();
int i = 1;
while (true)
{
   if (i < 37)
   {
      list.Add(i);
   }
   else
   {
      break;
   }
   i++;
}
    
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", list));
```